# How to create GitHub workflow for Azure container group deployment to ACI?

Tags: azure, docker, github, .net-core, containers

Microsoft provides documentation link and Azure CLI extension for deploying **single** `container` (no **group** of containers, using `docker-compose` or other containers grouping tool) to Azure Container Instance:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-github-action#configure-github-workflow

https://github.com/Azure/deploy-to-azure-cli-extension

How to modify this example GitHub workflow YAML file from documentation to achieve same effect for containers group, using in example `docker-compose`:

```yaml
on: [push]
name: Linux_Container_Workflow

jobs:
    build-and-deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        # checkout the repo
        - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
          uses: actions/checkout@main
          
        - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
          uses: azure/login@v1
          with:
            creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
        
        - name: 'Build and push image'
          uses: azure/docker-login@v1
          with:
            login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
            username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
            password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
        - run: |
            docker build . -t ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/sampleapp:${{ github.sha }}
            docker push ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/sampleapp:${{ github.sha }}

        - name: 'Deploy to Azure Container Instances'
          uses: 'azure/aci-deploy@v1'
          with:
            resource-group: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}
            dns-name-label: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}${{ github.run_number }}
            image: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/sampleapp:${{ github.sha }}
            registry-login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
            registry-username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
            registry-password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
            name: aci-sampleapp
            location: 'west us'
```

Comment: Got the same question as you...

Answer (score 0):

Now I think the idea of creating YAML GitHub workflow file to handle group of containers is bad approach. Building & pushing just one single image of container is enough: if we update image of concrete container, which is already in group of containers, this container will be automatically updated. Our **container image's Azure Container Registry** is linked to **container group's Azure Container Instance**

Comment: Have you been able to make your docker-compose file to work with Azure Container Instance ?

Comment: I found this article which talk about few solutions : https://dev.to/omiossec/using-azure-container-instance-with-multiple-containers-43fd

Comment: Ok, nice that u managed to handle it. This article talks about what i talked about in my answer: u can use containers group in Azure instead of docker-compose file : ) I mentioned that Azure Container Registry is linked to containers group. if i correctly remember, u can add one or more images to Azure Container Registry and these all images will be executed as containers in single group (this single group of containers is Azure Container Instance)